# Coloring elements of $A_1, ..., A_m$ where $|A_i| = n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polya-counting-theory

> Let $A_1, ..., A_m$ be separable $n$-elements sets. We color elements
>   of these sets in use of $2$ colors, but we consider two coloring as
>   the same if one we can get from other by changing order of sets and
>   then permuting elements inside sets. Find number of different
>   coloring.

After some trying I failed during construction of polyi approach for this task (I had a problem with describing elements of group $S_n \oplus S_m$.

My another observation is trivial but maybe helpful there:
Due to conditions, we can color each set $A_i$ on $n+1$ ways (we can choose if $0,1,...,n$ balls inside sets are white, other will be blue).
That approach solves:

> permuting elements inside sets.

But I have no idea how to consider this statement:

> if one we can get from other by changing order of sets

Comment: By "separable" $n$-element sets do you mean that the sets are disjoint?  Or something else, e.g. no two of the sets $A_i$ are the same (they are "distinguishable").

Comment: I mean that they are disjoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider $m \times n$ matrices with elements from $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to make sense of the coloring being closed under permutations of the sets is if all the sets are identical, $A_i = A_1,$ and then if the coloring must be consistently defined across all the sets, it would be equivalent to just define a coloring on a single set, which is boring, so I'll assume the coloring **need not** come from a single function $\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i \to \{0,1\}.$  All this I say as a precursor to the answer to show why clarification is important.

---

Anyway, under that interpretation, you're just counting the number of non-decreasing sequences of length $m$ with elements from $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}.$  This is counted by "stars and bars" as $$\binom{m+n}{m}$$

On the other hand, if my interpretation I wrote above isn't what you meant, then all bets are off.